# Why putting components in different <Route> position in <Switch> can lead to different visual outputs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I had followed the React Router document https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start and tried to follow these code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

For the `<Switch>` block, I put these  components like this below, the browser will work normally.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

But when I rearrange these components by letting the **Home** component into the first route:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

The browser will keep displaying the **Home** component even I change the url to `/about` or `/users`.

Why putting components in different `<Route>` position can lead to different visual outputs in React Router DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the exact option to the "/" route, otherwise It'll always match

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 1):

it's using a `grep` to match your routes. as soon as it hits the first matching one, it will display that one.

use the option `exact` to ensure the route matches exactly.